# WPF Multilingual GUI Switch-on-the-fly

Tags: wpf, multilingual

resource files are already created.
swtich the language after a restart of the app works currently.

is it possible to switch the language of the gui(Ribbon) on the fly ?

already tried:
change cultureinfo and invoke initializecomponents doesn't work.

Comment: What technique are you using for localization? LocBaml? Resx files? something else?

Answer (score 1):

I've bounced on this topic too a while ago. What i found was that it is possible, but it will take some effort. The only solution i recall is that you quit your application. At that moment a batch starts which will relaunch your application so the user won't freak out when the app suddenly quits and disappears. When your app has relaunched, it will reload all ui elements with the appropriate culture.

I haven't used this method because i don't like having to quit my app in order to make changes. But it is possible.

What you are experiencing is that the culture does change in your app, but your controls aren't updated accordingly. A restart "fixes" this.

Hope this helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with the same problem and found a solution that works for me. It does not require converters, but a piece of code is still necessary. The  .Net 4.5 framework is used.

Two unobvious things are needed in order to switch languages on-the-fly:

1. Use another flavour of binding to static properties, replace
   `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Resources.LocalizedString}}"/>` with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(p:Resources.LocalizedString)}"/>`. (The binding syntax with parentheses is used for attached properties and static properties. As a side effect, the XAML designer will show empty strings for  these properties.)
2. Change notifications do not work with resources. To workaround that, static bindings are manually refreshed by the following code:

   ```
   // ... after the current culture has changed
   UpdateStaticBindings(Application.Current.MainWindow, typeof(Properties.Resources), true);

   /// <summary>
   /// Update all properties bound to properties of the given static class.
   /// Only update bindings like "{Binding Path=(namespace:staticClass.property)}".
   /// Bindings like "{Binding Source={x:Static namespace:staticClass.property}}" cannot be updated.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="obj">Object that must be updated, normally the main window</param>
   /// <param name="staticClass">The static class that is used as the binding source, normally Properties.Resources</param>
   /// <param name="recursive">true: update all child objects too</param>
   static void UpdateStaticBindings(DependencyObject obj, Type staticClass, bool recursive)
   {
       // Update bindings for all properties that are statically bound to
       // static properties of the given static class
       if (obj != null)
       {
           MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(obj);

           if (markupObject != null)
           {
               foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
               {
                   if (mp.DependencyProperty != null)
                   {
                       BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(obj, mp.DependencyProperty) as BindingExpression;

                       if (be != null)
                       {
                           // Only update bindings like "{Binding Path=(namespace:staticClass.property)}"
                           if (be.ParentBinding.Path.PathParameters.Count == 1)
                           {
                               MemberInfo mi = be.ParentBinding.Path.PathParameters[0] as MemberInfo;
                               if (mi != null && mi.DeclaringType.Equals(staticClass))
                               {
                                   be.UpdateTarget();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           // Iterate children, if requested
           if (recursive)
           {
               foreach(object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj))
               {
                   UpdateStaticBindings(child as DependencyObject, staticClass, true);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```